# Heroku ECONNREFUSED with most console commands

Tags: deployment, heroku, ruby, ruby-on-rails, postgres

I'm on Ubuntu 20, working on a Rails 6.05 project with a Postgres DB. I've succesfully created a Heroku app using `heroku create appname` and then deployed the Rails app using `git push heroku master`.

The app/website is accessible and works fine on Heroku, but I'm not being able to run most console commands using the Heroku `cli`.

I can deploy as described above, and also set environment variables via `heroku config:set TWILIO_KEY='123'`, but commands like `heroku run rails db:migrate`, `heroku run rails console` and most if not any other commands that I try to run via heroku run command return the following error (IP changes every time):

```
Running rails console on ⬢ appname... done
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 54.175.164.234:5000
```

Right after I run any of these commands from my console, I can see the app logs on Heroku updating accordingly and throwing an error.

For example, for the `heroku run rails console` command executed above, the app logs show:

```
2022-05-31T00:42:11.048694+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `rails console` by user email@email.com
2022-05-31T00:44:34.314621+00:00 heroku[run.6356]: Awaiting client
2022-05-31T00:44:34.307905+00:00 heroku[run.6356]: State changed from starting to up
2022-05-31T00:45:04.332589+00:00 heroku[run.6356]: Process exited with status 128
2022-05-31T00:45:04.332006+00:00 heroku[run.6356]: Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process
2022-05-31T00:45:04.389840+00:00 heroku[run.6356]: State changed from up to complete
```

The Heroku docs do not provide more information on `R13` or status 128 error codes.

The error code itself does not provide any other information regarding the connection to what is failing either.

**Troubleshooting:** Since it clearly doesn't seem to be a connection issue with Heroku itself but rather the project, I  did a clean Ubuntu install on a laptop, disabled all firewall rules and attempted to run `heroku run rails console` on both new and old projects that I used to manage just fine.
To my surprise (not) I get the same error on all the projects I try to connect to, new or old.

This got me thinking, could it be a Postgres connection problem of some sort? Is there anything that I could have missed in the setup (eg: in `config/environments/production.rb` or `database.yml`) when deploying an app with a Postgres DB to production that might be causing the problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to verify it's not a connection issue - can you [telnet Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#troubleshooting)?

Comment: Hello. I'm trying to run the command suggested in the official docs you provided and I get `telnet: could not resolve rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com/5000: Name or service not known
`

Comment: Also, I can push to Heroku, set env variables, turn maintenance mode on/off. It seems the connection works, but I can't attach to the Heroku console from my console, as the error in the Heroku logs show.

Comment: Does `telnet 54.175.164.234 5000` work from your box? (IP taken from your output.)

Comment: No, I'm getting `Trying 54.175.164.234...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
` . Heroku's IP is dynamic and changes everytime, but the error is the same.

Comment: I also left a `tcpdump` running while trying `heroku run rails console` and I get an `ack` with the `[R.]` flag from Heroku. I don't understand but it is like if Heroku was denying the connection. I wish I could contact support on the free version..

Comment: [Apparently](https://telnet-online.net/) 54.175.164.234 is listening on 5000, but your box can't access it, although your CLI wants. I would work on that.

Comment: Thanks. This got me on the right track. I thought it was something with the app configuration, but it was indeed a problem with my ISP. I ran a `tracert` on the IP listed above and could easily see that it could not find a route to the Heroku servers. I tried using a VPN and it worked. Now I will test if changing the Heroku region fixes the problem, as it should use a different route to reach the Heroku servers. That will hopefully fix the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was related to my ISP blocking connections using port 5000, and it was evident when running a `telnet` I could not connect directly to the server either.

A workaround that works if you can't get your ISP to fix it is using a VPN.